# junit test mockito NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am writing a JUnit test case using Mockito and I am getting a NullPointerException.

In my Code it's like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrganizationServiceImpl implements OrganizationService {

 private final OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

 private final OrganizationMapper organizationMapper;

 private final OrganizationSearchRepository organizationSearchRepository;

 public OrganizationServiceImpl(OrganizationRepository organizationRepository, OrganizationMapper organizationMapper,
  OrganizationSearchRepository organizationSearchRepository) {
 this.organizationRepository = organizationRepository;
 this.organizationMapper = organizationMapper;
 this.organizationSearchRepository = organizationSearchRepository;
}

 @Override
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public List<OrganizationDTO> findAll() {
  return organizationRepository.findAll().stream().map(organizationMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
 }
}



@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OrganizationServiceTest {

 @Mock
 private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

 @InjectMocks
 private OrganizationServiceImpl organizationService;

 OrganizationMapper organizationMapper = OrganizationMapper.INSTANCE;

 @Before
 public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }

 @Test
 public void testGetAllOrganization() {
    List<Organization> organizationList = Arrays.asList(organizationInit());

    when(organizationRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(organizationList);

    List<OrganizationDTO> result = organizationService.findAll(); //NullPointerException
    assertEquals(3, result.size());
 }
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.prg.apags.service.impl.OrganizationServiceImpl.findAll(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:57)
>       at com.prg.apags.service.OrganizationServiceTest.testGetAllOrganization(OrganizationServiceTest.java:92)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
>       at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Comment: Using the `MockitoJUnitRunner` *and* calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` before the tests is redundant, because the former should have already initialized the mocks and injected them. Maybe try to remove the `setup()` method?

Comment: i removed the setup() method but it show me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never mocking or injecting `OrganizationMapper` into your Service. What `InjectMocks` does is inject what you annotate with `Mock` into your `OrganizationServiceImpl`, but since you're not using `Mock` on `OrganizationMapper`, mockito doesn't know that it needs to use it. Something like this should fix it:

```
public class OrganizationServiceTest {

 private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

 private OrganizationServiceImpl organizationService;

 private OrganizationSearchRepository searchRepository;

 private OrganizationMapper organizationMapper = OrganizationMapper.INSTANCE;

 @Before
 public void setup() {
    organizationRepository = Mockito.mock(OrganizationRepository.class);
    searchRepository = Mockito.mock(OrganizationSearchRepository.class);
    organizationService = new OrganizationServiceImpl(organizationRepository, organizationMapper, searchRepository);
 }

 @Test
 public void testGetAllOrganization() {
    List<Organization> organizationList = Arrays.asList(organizationInit());

    when(organizationRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(organizationList);

    List<OrganizationDTO> result = organizationService.findAll();
    assertEquals(3, result.size());
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried your method but it's the same result, and I tried a method in this article https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/  but it's the same result, i don't know what the problem is exactly :/

Comment: What if you initialize `organizationMapper` also in the `setUp`? Also, try breaking up `findAll` on `OrganizationServiceImpl` into several lines, that could help you identify exactly what is causing the exception

Comment: The problem is that i injected the logger with @Autowired in the OrganizationServiceImpl class, do i have to inject it also into the constructor?

Comment: Oh, there was no logger mentioned in your OP... yes, if you're calling a method on the logger you have to either inject it explicitly in the constructor or mock it in some way. You won't need to mock the method call since it returns `void`. My suggestion would be to either make the dependency explicit through a constructor parameter/passing it to `findAll` as a parameter, or to declare the logger as a static constant in the class and initialize it with `LoggerFactory`